# Java. Compile/Execute 2 .java 1 package command line

Tags: java, compilation, package, execution

These are my two .java, the fisrt one:

```
package net.utils.image;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class BufferedImageSplitter {

    protected BufferedImage image;
    protected BufferedImage[] splittedImages;

     public static BufferedImageSplitter getInstance( String path ) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File( path );  
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        return new BufferedImageSplitter( fis );
    }

    public BufferedImageSplitter(InputStream image) throws IOException {
        this.image = ImageIO.read(image);
    }

    public BufferedImageSplitter(FileInputStream image) throws IOException {
        this.image = ImageIO.read(image);
    }

    public BufferedImageSplitter(File image) throws IOException {
        this.image = ImageIO.read( image );
    }

    public BufferedImageSplitter(URL image) throws IOException {
        this.image = ImageIO.read( image );
    }

    public BufferedImage[] split(int height) {
        int width = this.image.getWidth();
        int rows = (int) Math.ceil( (float) this.image.getHeight() / (float) height );

        this.splittedImages = new BufferedImage[rows]; // Image array to hold
                                                        // image chunks
        for (int count = 0; count < rows; count++) {
            Graphics2D gr = null;
            int minHeightOffset = height * count;
            int maxHeightOffset = Math.min( image.getHeight() , height * count + height );
            int splitHeight = maxHeightOffset - minHeightOffset;

            // Initialize the image array with image chunks
            this.splittedImages[count] = new BufferedImage(width, splitHeight,
                    this.image.getType());

            // draws the image chunk
            gr = this.splittedImages[count].createGraphics();
            gr.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, width, splitHeight, 0,
                    minHeightOffset, width, maxHeightOffset, null);
            gr.dispose();

        }
        return this.splittedImages;
    }

    public void saveFiles(String FormatName, String ImageName ) throws IOException {

        //writing mini images into image files  
        for (int i = 0; i < this.splittedImages.length; i++) {  

            String padding = String.format("%03d", i);


            ImageIO.write(this.splittedImages[i], FormatName, new File( ImageName + padding + "." + FormatName));  
        }
    }

}
```

And the second one which contains the main class:

```
package net.utils.image;

import java.io.*;

public class MainSplitter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // File file = new
        // File("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrador\\Mis documentos\\b12.png");
        // FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        // BufferedImageSplitter imageSplitter = new BufferedImageSplitter(fis);

        if (args.length != 3) {

            System.out.println("Parametros incorrectos. Inserta"
                    + " <path imagen> <formato imagen> <nombre imagen>");
            System.exit(0);

        }

        String path_img = args[0];

        String format = args[1];

        String name_img = args[2];

        BufferedImageSplitter imageSplitter = BufferedImageSplitter
                .getInstance(path_img);
        imageSplitter.split(500);
        imageSplitter.saveFiles(format, name_img);

    }
}
```

And this is what I have tried so far without success:

My structure of the files is:  /root and there I have both .java

1) 1.1 javac *.java  (it compiles right)
   1.2 java MainSplitter
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MainSplitter (wrong name: net/utils/image/MainSplitter)

2) 2.1 javac -cp . *.java
   2.2 java cp . *.java
   Again the same error

3) 3.1 javac *.java
   3.2 java java net.utils.image.MainSplitter.main
Error: Could not find or load main class net.utils.image.MainSplitter.main

4) I have done a restructure of the files and put both .java in this directory:   root/net/utils/image and then:

4.1 javac -cp . *java
    java -cp . MainSplitter
    Again the first error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MainSplitter (wrong name: net/utils/image/MainSplitter).

I might have a problem with cp but don't really know, probably is easy but I am stuck, can't execute it.
Thank you in advance, I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your java file needs to be in a directory reflecting the package name:

```
net/utils/image/MainSplitter.java

$ javac net/utils/image/*.java

$ java -cp . net.utils.image.MainSplitter
```

Comment: Thank you very much really, I have done that and it works, from the root directory.
The -cp . works because it goes for the .class I have in the current directory doesn't it ¿? Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Hi you compile `MainSplitter` first.
Then check you have same package which holds your both classes.
I hope this help.